# Issues installing packages with NPM

Tags: node-sass

I'm trying to install Windows-Build-Tools using NPM.
However, when I run the below command I  get an error:

```
npm install --global --production windows-build-tools
```

Full Outpet

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32> npm install --global --production windows-build-tools
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported

> windows-build-tools@5.2.2 postinstall C:\Users\hp\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\windows-build-tools
> node ./dist/index.js



Downloading python-2.7.15.amd64.msi
Error: aborted
Downloading Python failed. Error: Error: aborted
    at connResetException (node:internal/errors:631:14)
    at TLSSocket.socketCloseListener (node:_http_client:438:27)
    at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:388:22)
    at node:net:666:12
    at TCP.done (node:_tls_wrap:573:7) {
  code: 'ECONNRESET'
}
```

Comment: It looks like you cannot make an HTTPS connection from your host to download Python. Check your network setup or proxies.

Comment: How to do that can you please explain ?